# RestTemplate: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found exception

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am trying to parse following xml response in spring boot:

Response structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE RESULT SYSTEM 'http://www.example.com/example/exampleV1.00.dtd'>
<RESULT REQID ='10961549902'>
    <MID SUBMITDATE='2017-08-14 17:17:29' ID='1' TAG = 'null' TID = '24180566483'></MID>
</RESULT>
```

Api call from Service:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();    
restTemplate.getForObject("http://www.exampleUrl.com",ResponseXml.class);
```

ResponseXml.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "RESULT")
public class ResponseXml implements Serializable{

    @XmlAttribute(name="REQID")
    private long requestId;

    @XmlElement(name = "MID")
    private long MID;

    public ResponseXml() {
      super();
    }

    public ResponseXml(long requestId) {
      super();
      this.requestId = requestId;
    }

    //getter setter

    public class MID {

    @XmlAttribute(name="SUBMITDATE")
    private Date submitDate;
    @XmlAttribute(name="ID")
    private Long id;
    @XmlAttribute(name="TAG")
    private Long tag;
    @XmlAttribute(name="TID")
    private Long tid;

    //getter setter
  }
}
```

Exception thrown:

```
Method threw 'org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException' exception.

Detailed message: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found 
for response type [class com.hk.response.sms.NetcoreResponseXml] 
and content type [text/plain;charset=UTF-8]
```

Please advice a fix, as to how do I parse xml response in JAVA spring boot? 
Why am I getting HttpMessageConverter exception despite adding @XmlRootElement annotation?

Comment: *content type [text/plain;charset=UTF-8]*: Spring can't consider the response as an XML response if th content type says it's plain text, instead of XML.

Comment: Response received is in XML, why is the content type read by spring is  [text/plain;charset=UTF-8]?

Comment: Because the server sending this response (`http://www.exampleUrl.com`) sets the content type of the response to text/plain instead of setting it to text/xml or application/xml.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not possible to fix server then configure message converted in a client application to accept `plain/text`:

```
// Create converter which supports text/plain mime type.
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
List<MediaType> mediaTypes = jsonConverter.getSupportedMediaTypes();
mediaTypes.add(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
jsonConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(mediaTypes);

// Alternatively get mapper as injected bean:
// @Inject
// private XmlMapper mapper;
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
// Register converter with RestTemplate
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(Arrays.asList(jsonConverter));
```